# Put condition on data-ng-attr-style

Tags: angularjs

My html is this:

```
<div data-ng-attr-style="background:url({{ backgroundImage}}) !important; background-size:cover;" ></div>
```

Now I can put the condition inside the double curly braces {{ only.

But it breaks if I put a condition.

I want to have a condition like this :

```
data-ng-attr-style="condition ? {background:url({{ backgroundImage}}) !important; background-size:cover;} : {display:none}"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to put your condition inside {{ }}:

```
data-ng-attr-style="{{ condition ? 'background:url(' + backgroundImage + ') !important; background-size:cover' : 'display: none' }}"
```

Or you put in several lines for better readability:

```
data-ng-attr-style="{{ 
    condition 
        ? 'background: url(' + backgroundImage + ') !important; background-size: cover;'
        : 'display: none' 
}}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `data-ng-style`

```
data-ng-style="{true : {'background': vm.backgroundImage } , false: {display: 'none'}}[vm.condition]"
```

Example Working:

http://codepen.io/gpincheiraa/pen/pgrRYG